Doubling constructions beyond classical groups: general principles?​
The doubling method for constructing integral representations of L-functions has been successfully applied to classical groups, as demonstrated in this paper. However, extending this method to a wider class of reductive groups, $G$, requires a systematic way to construct suitable "doubling groups," $H$.
Let $r_G: \hat{G} \rightarrow GL(N, \mathbb{C})$ be the L-group representation of $G$.
My question is if there are general principles or frameworks for constructing doubling groups $H$ beyond classical groups?
Can we formulate a construction of $H$ based on the structure of the root data of $G$, its L-group $\hat{G}$, or other inherent properties?
Ideally, the construction should be such that for a parabolic subgroup $P \subset H$ with Levi $M_P$, there exists an embedding
$$e: G \times G \hookrightarrow M_P,$$
and a character $\psi_U$ of the unipotent radical $U_P$ of $P$, such that
$$(e(G \times 1), e(1 \times G)) \subset \text{Stab}_{M_P}(\psi_U).$$
Are there existing constructions in Lie theory, such as the theory of reductive dual pairs, that could be relevant?​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
